# How to restart nginx with module on mac?

Tags: macos, nginx

I used brew to install nginx on Mac. And now I want to add a module http_realip. I found in the documentation that I should use the command `./configuration --with-http_realip_module` to add the module. But I can only find nginx.conf instead of the configuration file. Does anyone know what is the default path of configuration file on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using [nginx-full](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-nginx): `brew install nginx-full --with-realip`